# move_base's obstacles don't match laser scan output

Tags: navigation, move-base, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a (physical) robot with hokuyo laser mounted. I use rviz to see the raw scans. I also run move_base and subscribe to /move_base_node/local_costmap/obstacles on rviz to see the cells marked as obstacles by move_base.

One phenomenon I notice is that depending on the minimum obstacle height in costmap_common_params.yaml, move_base either sees no obstacles or sees obstacles in every cell. What I expect on rviz is that move_base marks a cell as an obstacle precisely when the laser scan indicates there's an obstacle on the cell. I have been trying to fine tune min_obstacle_height to this. Below 0.21 m, move_base marks every cell as an obstacle; above this, it sees no obstacle at all!

I don't know how to deal with this problem. My costmap_common_params file is:

`map_type: costmap
transform_tolerance: 0.3
obstacle_range: 2.0
raytrace_range: 1.5
inflation_radius: 2.5 //has to fine tune the parameter
observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: laser,
data_type: LaserScan,
topic: /scan,
expected_update_rate: 0.2,
observation_persistence: 2.0,
marking: true,
clearing: true,
min_obstacle_height: 0.20,
max_obstacle_height: 2.5}`

**Update after tfoote's comment**

Screenshot of rviz with obst height = .21 m :http://tiny.cc/a96op

Screenshot of rviz with obst height = .20 m: http://tiny.cc/yv4k5

Please see the captions of the images for more detail.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11024/move_base%27s-obstacles-don%27t-match-laser-scan-output/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2011-08-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-08-27**:
How far above the ground is your laser? ie what is the height of a laser scan in the odom frame? Also, screenshots from a topdownortho view would probably be better for visualizing this just to eliminate any perspective weirdness (I can't exactly tell if all of the scan is inside light blue or not).

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-08-25**:
Some screen shots would be really useful to help debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have fixed this - move_base was marking the vehicle's wheels and the laser mount point as obstacles. As a result, the vehicle wasn't moving properly. This wasn't obvious at all intially. After substantial tweaking of laser params, I was able to get move_base to move properly.

---

Originally posted by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) with karma: 365 on 2011-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-08-28**:
You may want to look into something like the http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_self_filter package or otherwise filter out the points (maybe with a min_range tweak) that correspond to your base.